# Android :- making app non shareable

Tags: android

I want to make an application which has to be very secured. So f I install an apk in a phone it should only work in that phone. When apk is shared it should not work.Can any one help me in implementing this.

One idea from my side is using an algorithm to generate password using device mac address and so the password won't work for two different devices to log in.Is there any way to get the MAC address( or something unique to device) in android from java? .Expecting alternate solutions!!

Comment: You can get device IMEI number easily. Thats also unique

Comment: how to get it from using java??

Comment: IMEI works only on devices having telephony service (not on many tablets)

Comment: Please see my updated answer about unique device identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented with IMEI number. So my apk is designed based on IMEI number.So it will check whether IMEI given matches with the device IMEI then only it will launch the new Activity, else it will exit.

```
TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tx);
    String ts = Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(ts);
    String imei = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
    if (imei.equals("<what we given inthe source>")) {
        // Launch the activity
    } else {
        // show an alert dialog and exit
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are distributing the app through [Google play store](https://play.google.com/store), you can make use of the Google Play [Application licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html).

You may read [Identifying App Installations](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) on Android Developer's Blog for a discussion about how to uniquely identify a device.